# Select only the dollar amounts for GETCHAR

Tags: c

Use getchar and while loop to only collect dollar amounts

I need my code to only collect dollar amounts from an input like if I type "I want 3 lollipops for $2.20 and 4 lollipops for $2.80" the output should be

$2.20

$2.80

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>



int main(void)

{

char ch;

char amount;

ch = getchar();



do{

if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' || ch == '$' || ch == '.')

{

amount = ch;

printf("%c", amount);

}

if(ch == ' ' )

{

amount = ch;

printf("\n ", amount);

}

}while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' );

return 0;

}
```

I know how to only get digits but I only want a number that has an $ at the beginning,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe kind of long, but straight forward solution. Note this will parse things like "$2.777" and will not something like this "$$2.77".

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void ParseAndPrintDollar() {
    char ch;
    char str[5];
    
    ch = getchar();
    if (! (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') )
        return;
    str[0] = ch;
    
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch != '.')
        return;
    str[1] = ch;
    
    ch = getchar();
    if (! (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') )
        return;
    str[2] = ch;
    
    ch = getchar();
    if (! (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') )
        return;
    str[3] = ch;
    str[4] = '\0';
    
    printf("$%s\n", str);
}

int main(void) {
  char ch;
  char amount;

  ch = getchar();

  do {
    if (ch == '$') {
        ParseAndPrintDollar();
    }
  } while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run this code . I think it will help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{

    char ch,amount;
    ch = getchar();
    bool dollarContext=false;
    do{
        if(ch == '$')dollarContext=true;

        if(dollarContext && ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '$' || ch == '.')){
            amount = ch;
            printf("%c",amount);
        }

        if(ch == ' ' )
        {
            dollarContext=false;
            amount = ch;
            printf("%c\n", amount);
        }

    }while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```